# Can't adjust volume on USB Headset

Tags: usb, 4.3-jelly-bean, htc, headphones

I've recently purchased a **Male Micro-USB to Female USB adapter (OTG)**.

Now, I've connected my USB Headphones (w/ Microphone) but I can't adjust the volume.

When I try, It either mutes it completely, or plays at 100% volume. 
Also, the Microphone doesn't work.

For some reason, the 'beats audio' doesn't work either.

I have a **HTC Butterfly**,

Android version: **4.3**

HTC Sense version: **5.5**

What could be the reason for not being able to adjust volume?

Comment: Beats Audio will not work with external USB headsets, since they contain their own DAC (Digital to Analog Converter).

Comment: @onik Alright, but how about the volume control? The 'lower' button mutes it, and 'higher' at max. Also sliding does the same. Is the DAC the same reason for that aswell?

Comment: That I can't answer, unfortunately.